# Where can I find Apple Clips' EDLs? (Or hack one?)

Tags: ios, video, video-editing, clips.app

I'm enjoying the free, nifty Clips app for iOS for making simple videos. But today after purging old photos from my Camera Roll, some of my projects in Clips were "Missing Items."

Thankfully, Clips includes a way to recover missing items from the Deleted Items album in Photos. Thus, I'm out of the woods for today.

But going forward, I realize that it would be helpful to have access to the filenames of all the images or videos that I use in my Clips projects. Or at least a way to save a copy of the items I used.

Unfortunately, Clips doesn’t show any filenames within projects.

With professional editing software, such as Final Cut Pro, you can locate/generate an [EDL, or *Edit Decision List.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_decision_list) This is often a text file or an XML file containing filenames and maybe timecodes, etc.

**Do EDLs exist for Apple Clips, or can I locate/generate something similar? I presume that the app uses a resource such as this to maintain data for open projects.**

**If not, is there any way for me to generate *some* sort of archive of the original files?**

**I welcome other ideas or suggestions.**

[image: screenshot of error in Apple Clips]